# How to calculate target impedance for the power trace if it is connected to multiple loads?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, decoupling, power-flow-analysis, power-integrity, hyperlynx

[image]

In this image, the source 3.3V, which is going to three loads(U1,U2,U3), that consumes current of 2A,0.5A and 1A respectively,
As the total current is 3.5A.
Lets consider allowable ripple,
U1-2%
U2-3%
U3-5%

Then calculating targeting impedance,

z=(3.3*0.02)/3.5 = 18mE

Here I have taken the minimum allowable voltage ripple in the rail and the total current in it. Whether this method is correct.
Or I need to calculate target impedance for three loads individually and do decoupling analysis. Like,
U1-(3.3*0.02)/2 = 33mE,
U2-(3.3*0.03)/0.5 = 198mE,
U3-(3.3*0.05)/1 = 165mE
Whether this procedure is correct?

Kindly clarify me, how to do decoupling analysis for this individual loads?

Comment: What is an 'E'. What other things are you assuming?

Comment: Total current doesn't matter, because DC isn't ripple; you need the maximum (worst case) change in current, perhaps in terms of step response (e.g. if this is a CPU or radio, perhaps it switches on and off abruptly), or if periodic, then at what frequencies.

Comment: E is nothing but ohms. So how will you do decoupling analysis, if single power rail is connected to multiple load IC's

Comment: What's the maximum step load change, in Ampere? And what's the reaction time of your buck converter (time from load change to regaining regulation)?

Comment: I just need to know the correct steps to do it.

Answer (score 2):

for calculating the target impedance you should know transient current (not maximum DC current). for example you can find transient current as a burst current in DDR datasheets.
Z=nominal voltage * % allowed ripple / transient current